# Is there a similar Linkaxes command in Octave?

Tags: matlab, matplotlib, octave

Is there any substitute method for linkaxes to use in Octave? I didn't find such command to implement in it.

Tks

Comment: Should be available in up2date octave versions: http://savannah.gnu.org/patch/?8398

Answer (score 1):

Linkaxes has been added to the development sources with changeset d1750be79dee [changeset d1750be79deee](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/rev/d1750be79dee). I'm sorry to tell you but you have to wait until 4.2 release or you try to use that function in your octave version.